# Can this CSS solution be improved for better responsiveness?

Tags: html, css

Basically I have this layout as you can see in the screenshot below.

[image]

```css
.project-name {
  margin-top: -50px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 100px solid #fff;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
}
.project-name h2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-mg-12">
        <img src="http://placeimg.com/1000/480/any" />
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="container">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-8 project-name">
 <h2>
 Project Name
 </h2>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

The CSS solution I have is working, I was wondering if there's a better way to get similar result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, the *issue* with your code is that you have currently *2 rows* and you are using positions and margins to force them to stick together.

When you do a *mobile responsive* change, you'll need to fix alot of these which may make it complicated.

Instead, focus on making the *parent div relatively positioned* and the *child divs to be absolutely positioned to its parent*.

That way, when you can use *media query* and easily adjust the values for each breakpoint when it comes to responsiveness.

**Try this:**

```css
.project-name {
  border-bottom: 100px solid #ffffff;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  height: 0;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100px;
}

.project-name h2 {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-mg-12">
        <img src="http://placeimg.com/1000/480/any" />
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-8 project-name">
       <h2>
       Project Name
       </h2>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

**Explanation:**

I've created a parent with a class name of `.project` and I've set that to have a *position of relative*.

Now, within `.project`, we have the image placed. And also, there is another div with a class name of `.project-name`.

What I am doing with `.project-name` is to make the shape using *borders*, then we make the *height to 0* so that the border collapses onto the h2 inside and then we can **absolutely position it to the bottom** of its parent div.

Go ahead and change those css values to suit your preferred margin lengths, widths and so on.

***EDIT 1:***

You've requested that the text *'project name'* has to be wrapped around a div with `.container` class.

I've updated the answer accordingly. Please take a look and also notice the following:

- added a new CSS as `.container` is bootstrap's global class, its not a good idea to edit it, thus, we reference that particular container by adding `.project .container`. This way, only the `.container` inside a `.project` will get affected, which is what we exactly want to do.
- The idea is still the same, since the new `.container` which is wrapping the word *'project name'* is inside its parent `.project`, we are again absolutely positioning it to its parent thus, we can just move it all the way to the left.

***Edit 2:***

- Copied the same *HTML* structure as what you provided
- Edited snippet

Comment: This approach works however I've limited freedom to where I can add 'project name'. It must be in a seperate container because of our modular design restrictions.

Comment: @shutupchigo So the only restriction / requirement is that the 'project name' has to be wrapped around `.container` div?

Comment: @shutupchigo Ok I've edited the snippet and added *Edit 1* to explain the changes.

Comment: It seems you misunderstood me. 'Project Name' container sits outside the 'image' container as I have mentioned in my original questions. Apologies for confusion.

Comment: @shutupchigo Ok I've copied your html structure and edited, please check.

Answer (score 0):

Something you could do is use the `::after` pseudo element and `background-image`

```
<div class="project__name"></div>
```

Then in your css

```
.project__name {
    position: relative;
    background-image: url('http://placeimg.com/1000/480/any');
    width: 100%;
}

.project__name::after {
    content: "Project Name";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; 
    left: 0;
    background: white;
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 90% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
    font-size: 10vw;
}
```

This would reduce your html down to one line and should (May need a little tinkering) give you a fairly similar result

Answer (score 0):

```css
.content > .project-name {
  margin-top: -50px;
  border-bottom: 100px solid #fff;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
  width: 62%;
}

.project-name h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-mg-12 content">
      <img src="http://placeimg.com/600/380/any" />
      <div class="col-md-8 project-name">
        <h2>
          Project Name
        </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```